# Redshift to dask DataFrame

Tags: amazon-redshift, dask

Does anyone have a nice neat and stable way to achieve the equivalent of:

```
pandas.read_sql(sql, con, chunksize=None)
```

and/or

```
pandas.read_sql_table(table_name, con, schema=None, chunksize=None)
```

connected to redshift with SQLAlchemy & psycopg2, directly into a dask DataFrame ?

The solution should be able to handle large amounts of data

Comment: Are you sure that this is the way you want to follow? On AWS we ended up doing this: create a temp table from query -> unload table to S3 (GZIP compressed) -> read from the folder with dask -> delete folder on S3. It is very fast and the impact on RS is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the `read_sql_table` function in dask.dataframe.

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table

```
>>> df = dd.read_sql_table('accounts', 'sqlite:///path/to/bank.db',
...                  npartitions=10, index_col='id')  # doctest: +SKIP
```

This relies on the `pandas.read_sql_table` function internally, so should be able to operate with the same restrictions, except that now you're asked to provide a number of partitions and an index column.

Comment: I am trying to use "dd.read_sql" to connect to RedShift, but how would I pass the uri parameter? In Redshift I have JBDC or Endpoint link!! And to your experience is this capable of loading 300 million row data with 16 GB RAM? In principle dask should, right? Also have tried this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004936/how-to-connect-to-a-cluster-in-amazon-redshift-using-sqlalchemy, but "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string" error.

Comment: @MRocklin if you want to use something like that in production you should change these all the time you increase your RS nodes.

Comment: @MajidMortazavi if by load you mean persist or compute I think you can't do it.