# Reading bigint (int8) column data from Redshift without Scientific Notation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, amazon-redshift, precision

I am reading data from Redshift using Pandas. I have one `bigint` (`int8`) column which is coming as exponential.
I tried following ways, but getting data truncation in those cases.

Sample Value of data in that column is : `635284328055690862`. It is reading as `6.352843e+17`.

I tried to convert that into `int64` in Python.

```
import numpy as np
df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].astype(np.int64)
```

Output in this case is : `635284328055690880`. Here I am loosing my data, it is scaling it to `0` at the end.

Expected Output: `635284328055690862`

Even, I am getting same result If I am doing this.

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
```

Output: `635284328055690880`

Expected Output: `635284328055690862`

It seems like this is normal Pandas behavior. I even tried creating a Dataframe using list and still getting the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
sample_data = [[635284328055690862, 758364950923147626], [np.NaN, np.NaN], [1, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)


Output:
0 635284328055690880 758364950923147648
1                nan                nan
2                  1                  3
```

What I have noticed is, whenever we have `nan` in dataframe, we are having this issue.

I am using below code to fetch data from Redshift.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
import pandas as pd  
connstr = 'redshift+psycopg2://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>/<db_name>' 
engine = create_engine(connstr) 
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():     
    df = pd.read_sql('''select * from schema.table_name''', conn)
print(df)
```

Please help me in fixing this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I understand the input correctly, I don't find any problem by doing the following :         `data = pd.Series([635284328055690862]).astype(int)`. It outputs `635284328055690862`

Comment: that is not a single data, it is one of the column value. @Grayrigel

Comment: You can refer to the updated example, that's exactly same issue.

Comment: Getting same output even by converting column to series: `data = pd.Series(df['column_name'].values).astype(np.int64)`. Here also output is same as mentioned in question. @Grayrigel

Comment: Yeah. I see now. I am not sure why this is the case.

Comment: How are you reading the data? I tried saving the sample data in the `csv` format and then, read using `pd.read_csv`, which works fine. Can  you check if it works for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221576/discussion-between-grayrigel-and-lonewalker).

Comment: I tried using creating Dataframe from list and reading data from Redshift Table. Just to let you know, we have this issue if we have `NULL`/`nan` value in data. @Grayrigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the fix can be instead of doing `select * from schema.table_name`. You can pass all columns separately and then cast the particular column.

Let's say, you have 5 columns in table and col2 is `bigint(int8)` column. So, you can read like below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
import pandas as pd  
connstr = 'redshift+psycopg2://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>/<db_name>' 
engine = create_engine(connstr) 
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():     
    df = pd.read_sql('''select col1, cast(col2 as int), col3, col4, col5... from schema.table_name''', conn)
print(df)
```

*P.S.: I am not sure this is the smartest solution but logically, if python is not able to cast to `int64` properly then we can read casted value from `SQL` itself.*

Further, I would like to try to cast int columns dynamically if it's length is more than 17.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because standard integer datatypes do not provide a way to represent missing data. Since floating point datatypes do provide `nan`, the old way of handling this was to convert numerical columns with missing data to `float`.

To correct this, pandas has introduced a [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html). If you were doing something as simple as reading a `csv`, you could explicitly specify this type in your call to `read_csv` like so:

```
>>> pandas.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype="Int64")
             column_a  column_b
0  635284328055690880     45564
1                <NA>        45
2                   1      <NA>
3                   1         5
```

However, the problem persists! It seems that even though 635284328055690862 can be represented as a 64-bit integer, at some point, `pandas` still passes the value through a floating-point conversion step, changing the value. This is pretty odd, and might even be worth raising as an issue with the pandas developers.

The best workaround I see in this scenario is to use the "object" datatype, like so:

```
>>> pandas.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype="object")
             column_a column_b
0  635284328055690862    45564
1                 NaN       45
2                   1      NaN
3                   1        5
```

This preserves the exact value of the large integer and also allows for `NaN` values. However, because these are now arrays of *python objects*, there will be a significant performance hit for compute-intensive tasks. Furthermore, on closer examination, it appears that these are Python `str` objects, so we still need another conversion step. To my surprise, there was no straightforward approach. This was the best I could do:

```
def col_to_intNA(col):
    return {ix: pandas.NA if pandas.isnull(v) else int(v)
            for ix, v in col.to_dict().items()}

sample = {col: col_to_intNA(sample[col])
          for col in sample.columns}
sample = pandas.DataFrame(sample, dtype="Int64")
```

This gives the desired result:

```
>>> sample
             column_a  column_b
0  635284328055690862     45564
1                <NA>        45
2                   1      <NA>
3                   1         5
>>> sample.dtypes
column_a    Int64
column_b    Int64
dtype: object
```

So that solves one problem. But a second problem arises, because to read from a Redshift database, you would normally use `read_sql`, which doesn't provide any way to specify data types.

So we'll roll our own! This is based on the code you posted, as well as some code from the `pandas_redshift` [library](https://github.com/agawronski/pandas_redshift/blob/master/pandas_redshift/core.py#L53). It uses `psycopg2` directly, rather than using `sqlalchemy`, because I am not sure `sqlalchemy` provides a `cursor_factory` parameter that accepts a [`RealDictCursor`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor). **Caveat: I have not tested this at all because I am too lazy to set up a postgres database just to test a StackOverflow answer! I think it should work but I am not certain. Please let me know whether it works and/or what needs to be corrected.**

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor  # Turn rows into proper dicts.

import pandas

def row_null_to_NA(row):
    return {col: pandas.NA if pandas.isnull(val) else val
            for col, val in row.items()}

connstr = 'redshift+psycopg2://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>/<db_name>'

try:  # `with conn:` only closes the transaction, not the connection 
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connstr, cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''select * from schema.table_name''')

    # The DataFrame constructor accepts generators of dictionary rows.
    df = pandas.DataFrame(
        (row_null_to_NA(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()), 
        dtype="Int64"
    )
finally:
    conn.close()

print(df)
```

Note that this assumes that all your columns are integer columns. You might need to load the data column-by-column if not.

Comment: that parameter `dtype=object/int64` is available only in `pd.read_csv()`. I am reading data from Redshift. @senderle

Comment: @LoneWalker interesting — can you point to the code or library you're using to read from Redshift? Is it [this](https://github.com/agawronski/pandas_redshift)?

Comment: I am using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40336183/7592515). Using  `sqlalchemy` library  and `redshift+psycopg2` driver to connect to redshift and reading table data from there. @senderle

Comment: I am using below code to read from Redshift table, in which I have one column which is bigint (int8) having that kind of data. Another observation, I would like to share, whenever I have number length `>16` and have `NULL` values. I face this issue.
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

connstr = 'redshift+psycopg2://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>/<db_name>'
engine = create_engine(connstr)
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    df = pd.read_sql('''select * from schema.table_name''', conn)
print(df)`

Comment: @LoneWalker I will give this some more thought but I see that `read_sql` does not provide this kind of flexibility. It seems like the best fix will be to load the data in a different format and then convert to a DataFrame manually. I wonder if there's a way to get the result of the SQL query in JSON and then process that.

Comment: @LoneWalker if you get a chance, please let me know whether the code I posted at the bottom of this answer works as expected.